Checking a Computation of Ricci and Scalar Curvature for the Reissner-Nordström metric in Initial Data for Einstein's Field Equations
Consider the three-manifold, $M^{3} = \mathbb{R}^{3} - \{ (0 ,0 , 0 \}$ and define the the following metric, $g$, on $M^{3}$ in spherical coordinates, $(r, \theta, \phi)$:
$$ds^{2} = \frac{(m+r)^{2}}{r^{2}} dr^{2} + (m+r)^{2} d\theta^{2} + (m+r)^{2}\sin^{2} \theta d\phi^{2} $$
This is the Reissner-Nordström Metric in the initial data formulation for Einstein's field equations, i.e.
$$g_{rr} = \frac{(m+r)^{2}}{r^{2}}$$
$$g_{\theta \theta} = (m+r)^{2}$$
$$g_{\phi \phi} = (m+r)^{2}\sin^{2}\theta$$
Since the metric is diagonal, we also have the following inverse terms:
$$g^{rr} = \frac{r^{2}}{(m+r)^{2}}$$
$$g^{\theta \theta} = \frac{1}{(m+r)^{2}}$$
$$g^{\phi \phi} = \frac{1}{(m+r)^{2}\sin^{2} \theta}$$
I computed the following partial derivatives of the metric:
\begin{align}
\partial_{r}(g_{rr}) &= -\frac{2m}{r^{2}}(1+\frac{m}{r}) \\
\partial_{\theta}(g_{rr}) &= \partial_{\phi}(g_{rr}) = 0 \\
\partial_{r}g_{\theta \theta} & = 2(r+m) \\
\partial_{\theta}g_{\theta \theta} &= \partial_{\phi}g_{\theta \theta} = 0 \\
\partial_{r}g_{\phi \phi} & = 2(r+m)\sin^{2} \theta \\
\partial_{\theta}g_{\phi \phi} & = 2(r+m)^{2}\sin \theta \cos \theta
\end{align}
These were then used to the compute the Christoffell Symbols of the Second Kind, $\Gamma_{ij}^{k} = \frac{1}{2}g^{kk}(\partial_{i}g_{kk}+\partial_{j}g_{kk} - \partial_{k}g_{ij})$  The nonzero Christofell Symbols are listed below:
\begin{equation} 
\Gamma_{rr}^{r} = \Gamma_{r\theta}^{r} = \Gamma_{r\phi}^{r} = -\frac{m}{(m+r)^{2}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\Gamma_{r\theta}^{\theta} = \Gamma_{r\phi}^{\theta} = \Gamma_{r \phi}^{\phi} = \frac{1}{r+m}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\Gamma_{rr}^{\theta} = \Gamma_{rr}^{\phi} =  \frac{2}{r+m}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\Gamma_{\theta \theta}^{r} = -\frac{r+m}{(1+\frac{m}{r})^{2}} = -\frac{r^{2}(r+m)}{(r+m)^{2}} = -\frac{r^{2}}{r+m}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\Gamma_{\phi \phi}^{r} = \frac{(r+m)\sin^{2} \theta}{(1+\frac{m}{r})^{2}} = \frac{r^{2}(r+m)\sin^{2} \theta}{(m+r)^{2}} = \frac{r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta}{m+r} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\Gamma_{r\theta}^{\phi} = \frac{1}{r+m} + \frac{\cos \theta}{(r+m)^{2}\sin \theta}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\Gamma_{\phi \phi}^{\theta} = -\sin \theta \cos \theta
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\Gamma_{\phi \theta}^{\phi} = \sin \theta \cos \theta
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\Gamma_{\theta \theta}^{\phi} = \frac{2\cos \theta}{\sin \theta}
\end{equation}
For the above metric, I have computed the following Ricci Curvature terms on $M^{3}$ using the following formula $
R_{ij} = \partial_{k}\Gamma_{ij}^{k}  - \partial_{j}\Gamma_{ik}^{k} + \Gamma_{ij}^{k}\Gamma_{km}^{m} - \Gamma_{im}^{k}\Gamma_{jk}^{m}$:
$$
R_{rr} = \frac{-(4r+2m)\sin \theta + 2((r+m)^{2}\sin^{2} \theta - 1)\cos \theta}{(r+m)^{3}\sin \theta}
$$
\begin{align} R_{r\theta} & = \frac{2r^{2}(m+r)\sin^{2} \theta - m\sin^{2} \theta - 2(m+r)^{2}\sin \theta - 2(m+r)^{2}\cos \theta \sin \theta - 2(m+r)^{2} \cos \theta \sin^{2} \theta}{(m+r)^{3}\sin \theta} \\
& - \frac{2(m+r)\cos^{2} \theta}{(m+r)^{3} \sin^{2} \theta}
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
R_{r\phi} = \frac{(\sin \theta \cos \theta)(m+r)^{2} + (\cos^{2} \theta - 2r^{2}\sin^{2} \theta)(m+r) - m}{(m+r)^{3}} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
R_{\theta \theta} = \frac{\sin \theta [m^{2} + 2mr - mr^{3} - r^{4} - (m+r)^{3}] - 2m (m+r)^{2}\cos \theta}{(m+r)^{4} \sin \theta}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
R_{\theta \phi} = \frac{r^{2}(m+r)^{2} - m(\sin \theta \cos \theta)(m+r)^{2} - m^{2} - (\sin^{2} \theta \cos^{2} \theta)(m+r)^{2}}{(m+r)^{4}}
\end{equation}
\begin{align} 
R_{\phi \phi} & = \sin^{2} \theta (1 +2\cos^{2} \theta) - \cos^{2} \theta + \frac{2r\sin^{2} \theta + \sin \theta \cos \theta}{m+r} \\
& - \frac{r^{2} \sin^{2} \theta (1+m)}{(m+r)^{2}} - \frac{m^{2}}{(m+r)^{4}} 
\end{align}
Combining these terms with the formulas for the inverse metric, $g^{-1}$, I computed the following formula for the scalar curvature $R$ of $(M^{3}, g)$:
\begin{align} 
R  = g^{ab}R_{ab} & =  \frac{2r^{2}((r+m)^{2}\sin^{2} \theta - 1)\cos \theta - r^{2}(4r + 2m)\sin \theta)}{(m+r)^{4}\sin \theta} \\
& + \frac{\sin \theta [m^{2} + 2mr - mr^{3} - r^{4} - (m+r)^{3}] - 2m(m+r)^{2}\cos \theta}{(m+r)^{6}\sin \theta} \\
& + \frac{1+2\cos^{2} \theta}{(m+r)^{2}} - \frac{\cos^{2} \theta}{(m+r)^{2}\sin^{2} \theta} + \frac{2r}{(m+r)^{3}} + \frac{\cos \theta}{(m+r)^{3}\sin \theta} \\
& - \frac{r^{2}(1+m)}{(m+r)^{4}} - \frac{m^{2}}{(m+r)^{6}\sin^{2} \theta}
\end{align}
Somehow, I have a feeling that the scalar curvature formula for this metric should have a simpler expression given that the Reissner-Nordström Metric is one of the simplest solutions for a charged black hole. Any intuition or insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Perhaps you could get more useful feedback if you show your work.

What does your metric tensor have to do with the Reissner-Nordström metric? After all your spacetime isnt even $4$ dimensional.

It's the initial data formulation, where we consider a Riemannian Three-Manifold with given metric that evolves into a four-dimensional spacetime via the Einstein Field Equations.
